# How to find out if print panel was closed successfully when printing from a PDFView

Tags: cocoa, nsdocument, pdfview

I need to know if the `PDFDocument` of a `PDFView` has been printed successfully in order to do some housekeeping afterwards.
When printing a regular `NSView` from `NSDocument`, I can do

```
    NSPrintOperation *op = [NSPrintOperation
                            printOperationWithView:myRegularPrintView
                            printInfo:self.printInfo];
    [op setCanSpawnSeparateThread:NO]; // Because we want to clean up afterwards
    [op setShowsPrintPanel:YES];
    
    [self runModalPrintOperation:op
                        delegate:self
                  didRunSelector:@selector(documentDidRunModalPrintOperation:success:contextInfo:)
                     contextInfo:NULL];
```

In the `documentDidRunModalPrintOperation` callback I can do the housekeeping. But printing the content of a `PDFView` only works correctly if I call

```
[myPDFView printWithInfo:[NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo] autoRotate:YES];
```

So I see no way to run the print operation with a callback function that is going to be called when the print panel is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since macOS 10.7 there is a function in `PDFDocument` which returns a `NSPrintOperation`, so one can simply do

```
    NSPrintOperation *op = [myPDFView.document printOperationForPrintInfo:self.printInfo scalingMode:kPDFPrintPageScaleToFit autoRotate:YES];
```

and then continue just like with a normal `NSView` and add a callback when calling `runModalPrintOperation`.